# Создание Word из данных sql на С#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-word

У меня есть бд. Я подключаюсь к ней и делаю запрос на интересующие поля. Как мне далее полученную информацию поместить в таблицу в Word (если быть точным, то как пустить цикл по полученной информации и как брать её конкретные значения). Возможно, есть вещи которые нужно делать иначе, посоветуйте.

```
int Rieltor_code = int.Parse(comboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString());
if (comboBox4.Text.Trim() == "Таблица") {

con.Open();
string query = "SELECT \"Object_nedvizimosti\".\"adress\", \"Prodaja\".\"Data\",
              \"Object_nedvizimosti\".\"stoimost\", \"Prodaja\".\"Stoimost\",
              (\"Prodaja\".\"Stoimost\" /\"Object_nedvizimosti\".\"stoimost\") " +
                "FROM \"Prodaja\", \"Object_nedvizimosti\", \"Rieltor\" " +
                "WHERE \"Prodaja\".\"Object_code\" = \"Object_nedvizimosti\".\"object_code\" 
                and" + " \"Object_nedvizimosti\".\"statuc\" = 0
                and \"Prodaja\".\"Rieltor_code\" = \"Rieltor\".\"rieltor_code\""
                + @Rieltor_code ;//еще нужна дата продажи
NpgsqlCommand com = new NpgsqlCommand(query, con);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

var Ворд1 = new Ворд.Word.Application();
Ворд1.Visible = true;
Ворд1.Documents.Add();
Ворд1.Selection.TypeText("ТАБЛИЦА ОБЪЕКТОВ НЕДВИЖИМОСТИ");
Ворд1.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Ворд1.Selection.Range, 30, 5,
Ворд.Word.WdDefaultTableBehavior.wdWord9TableBehavior,
Ворд.Word.WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitContent);
while (query.Read())
      {
         Ворд1.ActiveDocument.Tables[1].Cell(i, 1).Range.InsertAfter(query.GetValue(1).ToString());
         Ворд1.ActiveDocument.Tables[1].Cell(i, 2).Range.InsertAfter(query.GetValue(2).ToString());
         Ворд1.ActiveDocument.Tables[1].Cell(i, 3).Range.InsertAfter(query.GetValue(3).ToString());
         Ворд1.ActiveDocument.Tables[1].Cell(i, 4).Range.InsertAfter(query.GetValue(4).ToString());
         Ворд1.ActiveDocument.Tables[1].Cell(i, 5).Range.InsertAfter(query.GetValue(5).ToString());
            }
Ворд1.Selection.MoveDown(Ворд.Word.WdUnits.wdLine, 9); ; }
```

Comment: Для начала, замените скриншот на код.

Comment: а чисто средствами самого ворда это решить вам не проще?

Comment: Нет, необходимо через С#

Comment: извените но зачем мешать 2 языка руский и англиский

Comment: @Санитариум, всмысле? где?

Comment: var Ворд1 = new Ворд.Word.Application();

Comment: @Санитариум,  Какой был пример, тот и пришлось взять, заставить бы его работать для начала, а там можно и переименовыванием заняться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не из `query` нужно выполнять метод `Read`, так как это простая строка, а из переменной `com` нужно вызвать `ExecuteReader()`, сохранить возвращаемое значение в отдельную переменную и у же там вызывать `Read()`.

Собственно, на это вам намекает `IDE` делая красные подчеркивания.

Так же не понятно, зачем вы закрываете тут же соединение, как создали команду.

Что бы не использовать вырвиглазное экраниерование `"` через `\` можно воспользоваться [`@`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) перед текстовой строкой.

Comment: Разве @ не использует только в случаях, когда мы передаем значение поля? Я использую экранирование, для того чтобы он мог работать с  атрибутами бд. И не подскажите как мне задать I чтобы она была равна количеству строк из запроса?

Comment: Когда он внутри строки, мб, а когда он перед, то нет. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

Comment: мне кажется в данном случае имеется ввиду другое, тут версия постгресса заставляет его ставить, но я даже попробовал и он выдает ошибку. А есть предложения на счет как задать i?

Comment: Так в цикле while объявите переменную i и на каждой итерации цикла делайте инкремент.

Comment: Да, теперь работает, но я при запросе получают некое кол-во строк. Программа заполняет все сверху и последнюю, т.е. между верхними и последней есть пустые строки. Как можно от них либо избавится, либо сделать так, чтобы программа печатала все строки подряд, а потом оставляла пустые строки если нет объектов?

Comment: @Александр, Если их возвращает запрос, то добавьте фильтрацию в свой запрос.

Comment: всмысле? Допустим запрос вернул 4 строки, у меня 30 в таблице. Как дальше быть?

Comment: @Александр, какой запрос, такой и результат. Вы же идете по результатам запроса. Если он возвращает меньше, чем нужно, то проверяйте запрос.

Comment: запрос возвращает все верно, но при заполнении таблицы в word он заполняет первые 3 строки и последнюю и хотелось бы сделать так что бы он заполнял их все по порядку, пусть даже в конце будут пустые строки